# Inspecting elements within IFRAME in IE8 Developer tools works but has undesired offset effect

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

Suppose you have `iframe` elements in your page and you try to inspect its content. When you select a particular element within `iframe` content document, IE developer tools draws blue border around it, but with every nested `iframe` it adds additional 2 pixels offset.

You can see an example of this in this image below where I've manually added background to `html` and `body` elements making them visible in JSFiddle. I then selected `body` element within the `iframe` and as you can see indicator is offset by 2 pixels right and down.

[image: IE8 Dev tools offset]

If there was an additional `iframe` within this one, additional 2 pixels would be added getting to 4 pixels etc.

#### Is it possible to avoid this selected element indicator offset in Internet Explorer Developer Tools?

> ***Note**: Every time I have to use Internet Explorer a bit of me dies inside. If I have to use it along with developer tools a larger chunk of my life goes bananas.*